# Wordpress hook being called twice. Possible solutions?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, duplicates, hook

I have a Wordpress shop setup and there is a hook that is called to display product options selected by customer.

The hook is:

```
wpsc_after_cart_widget_item_name
<?php echo wpsc_cart_item_name(); ?></a>

<span style="font-size: 10px; line-height: 0.06em;">

<?php do_action ( "wpsc_after_cart_widget_item_name" ); ?></td>

<td><?php echo wpsc_cart_item_quantity(); ?></td>
<td><?php echo wpsc_cart_item_price(); ?></td>
<td class="cart-widget-remove"><form action="" method="post" class="adjustform">
    <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" name="key" 
           value="<?php echo wpsc_the_cart_item_key(); ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="wpsc_update_quantity" value="true" />
    <input class="remove_button" type="submit" />
```

I cannot figure out why it displays twice in the cart widget. I have thoroughly web-searched for filter hooks, troubleshooting, and even an ugly way of removing the duplicate text with jQuery, but found nothing.

Any help would be appreciated. My site is http://www.a1decals.com/products-page.

I can't post a pic yet but here is a link: http://i134.photobucket.com/albums/q87/mad_stallion_2006/screen001-3_zpsa94e087b.jpg

---

Update: here is the code for the shopping cart with your code inserted above and below the occurrences of the action hook you told me it relies on.

I'm not sure if I put the code in the wrong place or what, I am going to continue to move it around to see, but I'm still at a loss.

Sorry to put up all the code but i didn't know what might be relevant.

```
<?php global $wpsc_cart, $wpdb, $wpsc_checkout, $wpsc_gateway, $wpsc_coupons,     $wpsc_registration_error_messages;
$wpsc_checkout = new wpsc_checkout();
$wpsc_gateway = new wpsc_gateways();
$alt = 0;
$coupon_num = wpsc_get_customer_meta( 'coupon' );
if( $coupon_num )
   $wpsc_coupons = new wpsc_coupons( $coupon_num );

if(wpsc_cart_item_count() < 1) :
   _e('Oops, there is nothing in your cart.', 'wpsc') . "<a href=" . esc_url( get_option( "product_list_url" ) ) . ">" . __('Please visit our shop', 'wpsc') . "</a>";
   return;
endif;
?>
<div id="checkout_page_container"><br>
<h3><?php _e('', 'wpsc'); ?></h3></span>
<table class="checkout_cart">
   <tr class=" header">

<p style="font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; line-height: normal; text-align: center;"><span style="text-decoration: underline; color: #f4f4f4;"><span style="font-size: 18px;">Cart Records "Product Options" Like Color And Mirror Twice For Us  </p>

<tr style="background-color: #000078;">

      <th colspan="2"><?php _e('Product', 'wpsc'); ?></th>
      <th><?php _e('Quantity', 'wpsc'); ?></th>
      <th><?php _e('Price', 'wpsc'); ?></th>
      <th><?php _e('Total', 'wpsc'); ?></th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
   </tr>
   <?php while (wpsc_have_cart_items()) : wpsc_the_cart_item(); ?>
      <?php
       $alt++;
       if ($alt %2 == 1)
         $alt_class = 'alt';
       else
         $alt_class = '';
       ?>
      <?php  //this displays the confirm your order html ?>



<?php // This is used to fix the hook being called twice incorrectly ?>
<?php global $receivedItemHooks ?>
<?php if (!$receivedItemHooks) $receivedItemHooks = array() ?>

<?php if (!isset($receivedItemHooks[wpsc_the_cart_item_key()]): ?>



      <?php do_action ( "wpsc_before_checkout_cart_row" ); ?>
      <tr class="product_row product_row_<?php echo wpsc_the_cart_item_key(); ?> <?php echo $alt_class;?>">

         <td class="firstcol wpsc_product_image wpsc_product_image_<?php echo wpsc_the_cart_item_key(); ?>">
         <?php if('' != wpsc_cart_item_image()): ?>
            <?php do_action ( "wpsc_before_checkout_cart_item_image" ); ?>
            <img src="<?php echo wpsc_cart_item_image(); ?>" alt="<?php echo wpsc_cart_item_name(); ?>" title="<?php echo wpsc_cart_item_name(); ?>" class="product_image" />
            <?php do_action ( "wpsc_after_checkout_cart_item_image" ); ?>
         <?php else:
         /* I dont think this gets used anymore,, but left in for backwards compatibility */
         ?>
            <div class="item_no_image">
                <?php do_action ( "wpsc_before_checkout_cart_item_image" ); ?>
               <a href="<?php echo esc_url( wpsc_the_product_permalink() ); ?>">
               <span><?php _e('No Image','wpsc'); ?></span>

               </a>
                <?php do_action ( "wpsc_after_checkout_cart_item_image" ); ?>
            </div>
         <?php endif; ?>
         </td>







         <td class="wpsc_product_name wpsc_product_name_<?php echo wpsc_the_cart_item_key(); ?>">
            <?php do_action ( "wpsc_before_checkout_cart_item_name" ); ?>
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( wpsc_cart_item_url() );?>">


<span style="font-size: 12px;">
<?php echo wpsc_cart_item_name(); ?></a>
<span style="font-size: 12px;">

            <?php do_action ( "wpsc_after_checkout_cart_item_name" ); ?>
         </td>

         <td class="wpsc_product_quantity wpsc_product_quantity_<?php echo wpsc_the_cart_item_key(); ?>">
            <form action="<?php echo esc_url( get_option( 'shopping_cart_url' ) ); ?>" method="post" class="adjustform qty">
               <input type="text" name="quantity" size="2" value="<?php echo wpsc_cart_item_quantity(); ?>" />
               <input type="hidden" name="key" value="<?php echo wpsc_the_cart_item_key(); ?>" />
               <input type="hidden" name="wpsc_update_quantity" value="true" />
               <input type="submit" value="<?php _e('Update', 'wpsc'); ?>" name="submit" />
            </form>
         </td>


            <td><?php echo wpsc_cart_single_item_price(); ?></td>
         <td class="wpsc_product_price wpsc_product_price_<?php echo wpsc_the_cart_item_key(); ?>"><span class="pricedisplay"><?php echo wpsc_cart_item_price(); ?></span></td>

         <td class="wpsc_product_remove wpsc_product_remove_<?php echo wpsc_the_cart_item_key(); ?>">
            <form action="<?php echo esc_url( get_option( 'shopping_cart_url' ) ); ?>" method="post" class="adjustform remove">
               <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="0" />
               <input type="hidden" name="key" value="<?php echo wpsc_the_cart_item_key(); ?>" />
               <input type="hidden" name="wpsc_update_quantity" value="true" />
               <input type="submit" value="<?php _e('Remove', 'wpsc'); ?>" name="submit" />






<?php // Mark the item as rendered ?>
    <?php $receivedItemHooks[wpsc_the_cart_item_key()] = true ?>
<?php endif ?>







 </form>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <?php do_action ( "wpsc_after_checkout_cart_row" ); ?>
   <?php endwhile; ?>
   <?php //this HTML displays coupons if there are any active coupons to use ?>

   <?php

   if(wpsc_uses_coupons()): ?>

      <?php if(wpsc_coupons_error()): ?>
         <tr class="wpsc_coupon_row wpsc_coupon_error_row"><td colspan="6"><?php _e('Coupon is not valid.', 'wpsc'); ?></td></tr>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <tr class="wpsc_coupon_row">
         <td colspan="2"><?php _e('Enter coupon code :', 'wpsc'); ?></td>
         <td  colspan="4" class="coupon_code">
            <form  method="post" action="<?php echo esc_url( get_option( 'shopping_cart_url' ) ); ?>">
               <input type="text" name="coupon_num" id="coupon_num" value="<?php echo $wpsc_cart->coupons_name; ?>" />
               <input type="submit" value="<?php _e('Update', 'wpsc') ?>" />
            </form>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="wpsc_total_before_shipping">
          <td colspan="3"><?php _e('Cost before shipping:','wpsc'); ?></td>
          <td colspan="3" class="wpsc_total_amount_before_shipping"><?php echo wpsc_cart_total_widget(false,false,false);?></td>
      </tr>
   <?php endif; ?>
   </table>
   <!-- cart contents table close -->
  <?php if(wpsc_uses_shipping()): ?>
       <p class="wpsc_cost_before"></p>
   <?php endif; ?>
   <?php  //this HTML dispalys the calculate your order HTML   ?>

   <?php if(wpsc_has_category_and_country_conflict()): ?>
      <p class='validation-error'><?php echo esc_html( wpsc_get_customer_meta( 'category_shipping_conflict' ) ); ?></p>
   <?php endif; ?>

   <?php if(isset($_SESSION['WpscGatewayErrorMessage']) && $_SESSION['WpscGatewayErrorMessage'] != '') :?>
      <p class="validation-error"><?php echo $_SESSION['WpscGatewayErrorMessage']; ?></p>
   <?php
   endif;
   ?>

   <?php do_action('wpsc_before_shipping_of_shopping_cart'); ?>

   <div id="wpsc_shopping_cart_container">
   <?php if(wpsc_uses_shipping()) : ?>
      <h2><font color="#1956cf"><?php _e('Calculate Shipping Price', 'wpsc'); ?></font></h2>
      <table class="productcart">
         <tr class="wpsc_shipping_info">
            <td colspan="5">
               <?php _e('Please specify shipping location below to calculate your shipping costs', 'wpsc'); ?>
            </td>
         </tr>

         <?php if (!wpsc_have_shipping_quote()) : // No valid shipping quotes ?>
            <?php if (wpsc_have_valid_shipping_zipcode()) : ?>
                  <tr class='wpsc_update_location'>
                     <td colspan='5' class='shipping_error' >
                        <?php _e('Please provide a Zipcode and click Calculate in order to continue.', 'wpsc'); ?>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
            <?php else: ?>
               <tr class='wpsc_update_location_error'>
                  <td colspan='5' class='shipping_error' >
                     <?php _e('Sorry, online ordering is unavailable to this destination and/or weight. Please double check your destination details.', 'wpsc'); ?>
                  </td>
               </tr>
            <?php endif; ?>
         <?php endif; ?>
         <tr class='wpsc_change_country'>
            <td colspan='5'>
               <form name='change_country' id='change_country' action='' method='post'>
                  <?php echo wpsc_shipping_country_list();?>
                  <input type='hidden' name='wpsc_update_location' value='true' />
                  <input type='submit' name='wpsc_submit_zipcode' value='<?php esc_attr_e( 'Calculate', 'wpsc' ); ?>' />
               </form>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <?php if (wpsc_have_morethanone_shipping_quote()) :?>
            <?php while (wpsc_have_shipping_methods()) : wpsc_the_shipping_method(); ?>
                  <?php    if (!wpsc_have_shipping_quotes()) { continue; } // Don't display shipping method if it doesn't have at least one quote ?>
                  <tr class='wpsc_shipping_header'><td class='shipping_header' colspan='5'><?php echo wpsc_shipping_method_name().__(' - Choose a Shipping Rate', 'wpsc'); ?> </td></tr>
                  <?php while (wpsc_have_shipping_quotes()) : wpsc_the_shipping_quote();  ?>
                     <tr class='<?php echo wpsc_shipping_quote_html_id(); ?>'>
                        <td class='wpsc_shipping_quote_name wpsc_shipping_quote_name_<?php echo wpsc_shipping_quote_html_id(); ?>' colspan='3'>
                           <label for='<?php echo wpsc_shipping_quote_html_id(); ?>'><?php echo wpsc_shipping_quote_name(); ?></label>
                        </td>
                        <td class='wpsc_shipping_quote_price wpsc_shipping_quote_price_<?php echo wpsc_shipping_quote_html_id(); ?>' style='text-align:center;'>
                           <label for='<?php echo wpsc_shipping_quote_html_id(); ?>'><?php echo wpsc_shipping_quote_value(); ?></label>
                        </td>
                        <td class='wpsc_shipping_quote_radio wpsc_shipping_quote_radio_<?php echo wpsc_shipping_quote_html_id(); ?>' style='text-align:center;'>
                           <?php if(wpsc_have_morethanone_shipping_methods_and_quotes()): ?>
                              <input type='radio' id='<?php echo wpsc_shipping_quote_html_id(); ?>' <?php echo wpsc_shipping_quote_selected_state(); ?>  onclick='switchmethod("<?php echo wpsc_shipping_quote_name(); ?>", "<?php echo wpsc_shipping_method_internal_name(); ?>")' value='<?php echo wpsc_shipping_quote_value(true); ?>' name='shipping_method' />
                           <?php else: ?>
                              <input <?php echo wpsc_shipping_quote_selected_state(); ?> disabled='disabled' type='radio' id='<?php echo wpsc_shipping_quote_html_id(); ?>'  value='<?php echo wpsc_shipping_quote_value(true); ?>' name='shipping_method' />
                                 <?php wpsc_update_shipping_single_method(); ?>
                           <?php endif; ?>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                  <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
         <?php endif; ?>

         <?php wpsc_update_shipping_multiple_methods(); ?>


         <?php if (!wpsc_have_shipping_quote()) : // No valid shipping quotes ?>
               </table>
               </div>
            </div>
            <?php return; ?>
         <?php endif; ?>
      </table>
   <?php endif;  ?>

   <?php
      $wpec_taxes_controller = new wpec_taxes_controller();
      if($wpec_taxes_controller->wpec_taxes_isenabled()):
   ?>
      <table class="productcart">
         <tr class="total_price total_tax">
            <td colspan="3">
               <?php echo wpsc_display_tax_label(true); ?>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2">
               <span id="checkout_tax" class="pricedisplay checkout-tax"><?php echo wpsc_cart_tax(); ?></span>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>











   <?php endif; ?>
   <?php do_action('wpsc_before_form_of_shopping_cart'); ?>

    <?php if( ! empty( $wpsc_registration_error_messages ) ): ?>
        <p class="validation-error">
        <?php
        foreach( $wpsc_registration_error_messages as $user_error )
         echo $user_error."<br />\n";
        ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ( wpsc_show_user_login_form() && !is_user_logged_in() ): ?>
            <p><?php _e('You must sign in or register with us to continue with your purchase', 'wpsc');?></p>

<!--SOCIAL MEDIA CONNECT BUTTONS-->
<div>
<br>Make It Easy With Facebook and Twitter Connect. <br>
<a href="http://a1decals.com/wp-login.php?loginFacebook=1&redirect=http://a1decals.com" onclick="window.location = 'http://a1decals.com/wp-login.php?loginFacebook=1&redirect='+window.location.href; return false;"> <img src="http://a1decals.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/facebook_connect1.png" /> </a>
<a href="http://a1decals.com/wp-login.php?loginTwitter=1&redirect=http://a1decals.com" onclick="window.location = 'http://a1decals.com/wp-login.php?loginTwitter=1&redirect='+window.location.href; return false;"> <img src="http://a1decals.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/twitter_connect_button.gif" /> </a></div>



            <div class="wpsc_registration_form">

                <fieldset class='wpsc_registration_form'>
                    <h2><?php _e( 'Sign in', 'wpsc' ); ?></h2>
                    <?php
                    $args = array(
                        'remember' => false,
                        'redirect' => home_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] )
                    );
                    wp_login_form( $args );
                    ?>
                    <div class="wpsc_signup_text"><?php _e('If you have bought from us before please sign in here to purchase', 'wpsc');?></div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
   <table class='wpsc_checkout_table wpsc_checkout_table_totals'>
      <?php if(wpsc_uses_shipping()) : ?>
          <tr class="total_price total_shipping">
             <td class='wpsc_totals'>
                <?php _e('Total Shipping:', 'wpsc'); ?>
             </td>
             <td class='wpsc_totals'>
                <span id="checkout_shipping" class="pricedisplay checkout-shipping"><?php echo wpsc_cart_shipping(); ?></span>
             </td>
          </tr>
      <?php endif; ?>

     <?php if(wpsc_uses_coupons() && (wpsc_coupon_amount(false) > 0)): ?>
      <tr class="total_price">
         <td class='wpsc_totals'>
            <?php _e('Discount:', 'wpsc'); ?>
         </td>
         <td class='wpsc_totals'>
            <span id="coupons_amount" class="pricedisplay"><?php echo wpsc_coupon_amount(); ?></span>
          </td>
         </tr>
     <?php endif ?>



   <tr class='total_price'>
      <td class='wpsc_totals'>
      <?php _e('Total Price:', 'wpsc'); ?>
      </td>
      <td class='wpsc_totals'>
         <span id='checkout_total' class="pricedisplay checkout-total"><?php echo wpsc_cart_total(); ?></span>
      </td>
   </tr>
   </table>















    <form class='wpsc_checkout_forms' action='<?php echo esc_url( get_option( 'shopping_cart_url' ) ); ?>' method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <?php
      /**
       * Both the registration forms and the checkout details forms must be in the same form element as they are submitted together, you cannot have two form elements submit together without the use of JavaScript.
      */
      ?>

    <?php if(wpsc_show_user_login_form()):
          global $current_user;
          get_currentuserinfo();   ?>

        <div class="wpsc_registration_form">

            <fieldset class='wpsc_registration_form wpsc_right_registration'>
                <h2><?php _e('Join up now', 'wpsc');?></h2>

                <label><?php _e('Username:', 'wpsc'); ?></label>
                <input type="text" name="log" id="log" value="" size="20"/><br/>

                <label><?php _e('Password:', 'wpsc'); ?></label>
                <input type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd" value="" size="20" /><br />

                <label><?php _e('E-mail', 'wpsc'); ?>:</label>
                <input type="text" name="user_email" id="user_email" value="" size="20" /><br />
                <div class="wpsc_signup_text"><?php _e('Signing up is free and easy! please fill out your details your registration will happen automatically as you checkout. Don\'t forget to use your details to login with next time!', 'wpsc');?></div>
            </fieldset>

        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
   <?php endif; // closes user login form
      $misc_error_messages = wpsc_get_customer_meta( 'checkout_misc_error_messages' );
      if( ! empty( $misc_error_messages ) ): ?>
         <div class='login_error'>
            <?php foreach( $misc_error_messages as $user_error ){?>
               <p class='validation-error'><?php echo $user_error; ?></p>
               <?php } ?>
         </div>

      <?php
      endif;
      ?>
<?php ob_start(); ?>
   <table class='wpsc_checkout_table table-1'>
      <?php $i = 0;
      while (wpsc_have_checkout_items()) : wpsc_the_checkout_item(); ?>

        <?php if(wpsc_checkout_form_is_header() == true){
               $i++;
               //display headers for form fields ?>
               <?php if($i > 1):?>
                  </table>
                  <table class='wpsc_checkout_table table-<?php echo $i; ?>'>
               <?php endif; ?>

               <tr <?php echo wpsc_the_checkout_item_error_class();?>>
                  <td <?php wpsc_the_checkout_details_class(); ?> colspan='2'>
                     <h4><font color="#1956cf"><?php echo wpsc_checkout_form_name();?></h4>
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <?php if(wpsc_is_shipping_details()):?>
               <tr class='same_as_shipping_row'>
                  <td colspan ='2'>
                  <?php $checked = '';
                  $shipping_same_as_billing = wpsc_get_customer_meta( 'shipping_same_as_billing' );
                  if(isset($_POST['shippingSameBilling']) && $_POST['shippingSameBilling'])
                     $shipping_same_as_billing = true;
                  elseif(isset($_POST['submit']) && !isset($_POST['shippingSameBilling']))
                    $shipping_same_as_billing = false;
                  wpsc_update_customer_meta( 'shipping_same_as_billing', $shipping_same_as_billing );
                    if( $shipping_same_as_billing )
                        $checked = 'checked="checked"';
                   ?>
                    <label for='shippingSameBilling'><?php _e('Same as billing address:','wpsc'); ?></label>
                    <input type='checkbox' value='true' name='shippingSameBilling' id='shippingSameBilling' <?php echo $checked; ?> />
                    <br/><span id="shippingsameasbillingmessage"><?php _e('Your order will be shipped to the billing address', 'wpsc'); ?></span>
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <?php endif;

            // Not a header so start display form fields
            }elseif(wpsc_disregard_shipping_state_fields()){
            ?>
               <tr class='wpsc_hidden'>
                  <td class='<?php echo wpsc_checkout_form_element_id(); ?>'>
                     <label for='<?php echo wpsc_checkout_form_element_id(); ?>'>
                     <?php echo wpsc_checkout_form_name();?>
                     </label>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                     <?php echo wpsc_checkout_form_field();?>
                      <?php if(wpsc_the_checkout_item_error() != ''): ?>
                             <p class='validation-error'><?php echo wpsc_the_checkout_item_error(); ?></p>
                     <?php endif; ?>
                  </td>
               </tr>
            <?php
            }elseif(wpsc_disregard_billing_state_fields()){
            ?>
               <tr class='wpsc_hidden'>
                  <td class='<?php echo wpsc_checkout_form_element_id(); ?>'>
                     <label for='<?php echo wpsc_checkout_form_element_id(); ?>'>
                     <?php echo wpsc_checkout_form_name();?>
                     </label>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                     <?php echo wpsc_checkout_form_field();?>
                      <?php if(wpsc_the_checkout_item_error() != ''): ?>
                             <p class='validation-error'><?php echo wpsc_the_checkout_item_error(); ?></p>
                     <?php endif; ?>
                  </td>
               </tr>
            <?php
            }elseif( $wpsc_checkout->checkout_item->unique_name == 'billingemail'){ ?>
               <?php $email_markup =
               "<div class='wpsc_email_address'>
                  <p class='" . wpsc_checkout_form_element_id() . "'>
                     <label class='wpsc_email_address' for='" . wpsc_checkout_form_element_id() . "'>
                     " . __('Enter your email address', 'wpsc') . "
                     </label>
                  <p class='wpsc_email_address_p'>
                  <img src='https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/empty?s=60&amp;d=mm' id='wpsc_checkout_gravatar' />
                  " . wpsc_checkout_form_field();

                   if(wpsc_the_checkout_item_error() != '')
                      $email_markup .= "<p class='validation-error'>" . wpsc_the_checkout_item_error() . "</p>";
               $email_markup .= "</div>";
             }else{ ?>
            <tr>
               <td class='<?php echo wpsc_checkout_form_element_id(); ?>'>
                  <label for='<?php echo wpsc_checkout_form_element_id(); ?>'>
                  <?php echo wpsc_checkout_form_name();?>
                  </label>
               </td>
               <td>
                  <?php echo wpsc_checkout_form_field();?>
                   <?php if(wpsc_the_checkout_item_error() != ''): ?>
                          <p class='validation-error'><?php echo wpsc_the_checkout_item_error(); ?></p>
                  <?php endif; ?>
               </td>
            </tr>

         <?php }//endif; ?>

      <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php
    $buffer_contents = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    if(isset($email_markup))
        echo $email_markup;
    echo $buffer_contents;
?>

      <?php if (wpsc_show_find_us()) : ?>
      <tr>
         <td><label for='how_find_us'><?php _e('How did you find us' , 'wpsc'); ?></label></td>
         <td>
            <select name='how_find_us'>
               <option value='Word of Mouth'><?php _e('Word of mouth' , 'wpsc'); ?></option>
               <option value='Advertisement'><?php _e('Advertising' , 'wpsc'); ?></option>
               <option value='Internet'><?php _e('Internet' , 'wpsc'); ?></option>
               <option value='Customer'><?php _e('Existing Customer' , 'wpsc'); ?></option>
            </select>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php do_action('wpsc_inside_shopping_cart'); ?>

      <?php  //this HTML displays activated payment gateways   ?>
      <?php if(wpsc_gateway_count() > 1): // if we have more than one gateway enabled, offer the user a choice ?>
         <tr>
         <td colspan='2' class='wpsc_gateway_container'>
            <h3><font color="#1956cf"><?php _e('Payment Type', 'wpsc');?></font></h3>
            <?php while (wpsc_have_gateways()) : wpsc_the_gateway(); ?>
               <div class="custom_gateway">
                     <label><input type="radio" value="<?php echo wpsc_gateway_internal_name();?>" <?php echo wpsc_gateway_is_checked(); ?> name="custom_gateway" class="custom_gateway"/><?php echo wpsc_gateway_name(); ?>
                        <?php if( wpsc_show_gateway_image() ): ?>
                        <img src="<?php echo wpsc_gateway_image_url(); ?>" alt="<?php echo wpsc_gateway_name(); ?>" style="position:relative; top:5px;" />
                        <?php endif; ?>
                     </label>
```

Comment: If you'll only render one of these on a page, you could set a `global` variable and only render if it is not set. Bear in mind it's a seriously inelegant solution, but it'd work... however it would be better to get in touch with the authors/support for the shopping cart, to see why the hook is raised twice.

Comment: i did contact him. he wants minimum 68 dollars to even look at it. i cant blame him though hes a developer.

Comment: can you give me some code to try for the inelegant solution

Comment: Will you only ever need this once on any page?

Comment: Indeed. But is it possible to have this hook called twice on the page? For example, how many times should this hook be called if you have two items in your basket? Once per item, I would have thought?

Comment: yes, i think it loops this hook for each product.

Comment: for sure it calls this hook for each item

Comment: I've rolled back to your original question and inserted your update - it is best here not to remove your original text, since doing so makes it confusing for new readers who may wish to assist.

Comment: One problem I can see is that my `endif` cuts off the next three tags in your HTML (`/form`, `/td` and `/tr`) which in all likelihood will render an incorrectly nested document. Move the three-line block from `<?php // Mark the item as rendered ?>` to `<?php endif ?>` to after the closing `tr` and try again.

Comment: Also, your HTML/PHP structures aren't well nested - go through the whole snippet and fix the indentation, so it is clear where you are entering/leaving a block/loop. That won't fix anything in itself, but will make the code easier to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested:

```
<?php // This is used to fix the hook being called twice incorrectly ?>
<?php global $receivedItemHooks ?>
<?php if (!$receivedItemHooks) $receivedItemHooks = array() ?>

<?php if (!isset($receivedItemHooks[wpsc_the_cart_item_key()]): ?>

    <!-- Your HTML goes here -->

    <?php // Mark the item as rendered ?>
    <?php $receivedItemHooks[wpsc_the_cart_item_key()] = true ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

This relies on the function `wpsc_the_cart_item_key()` returning a unique reference for each basket item (not a product code, since that would not be unique if a product is added to the basket as two individual items, rather than one item with a quantity of 2).

This should be a good start, but don't be afraid to modify and debug!

Comment: i am looking over the cade and i want to make sure i understand.

Comment: ok i am new here so i edited my question with the new information. im stoked you are helping me halfer. it seems like this might be over the head of a $5 coder on fiverr.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where wordpres kept adding twice to database and emailing twice, After not being able to find solutions for weeks, I finally found some anwsers which had to do with improper html, it finally turned out to be the table surrounding the php that was cuasing this, I have no idea why but once I **replaced the table with divs** it worked completely fine. Although I checked the table and it seemed that it was properly constructed my guess it could be some kind of wordpress flaw that occurs becuase of tables. I know it doesn't make sense but in my case it was the solution so I highly suggest you replace the tables with divs and hopefully that will work for you. Good luck hope that solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can go around it by sessions

```
<?php
add_action('init','my');
function my()
{

    session_start();

    if( ! isset( $_SESSION['okay'] ) )
    {
        $obj = new Hasan;

        $obj->title = "we will we will rock you";

        $obj->save();

        $_SESSION['okay'] = 'okay';
    }

    else
    {
    unset($_SESSION['okay']);
    }

 }
```